# Arrastar y soltar elementos dinamicamente dibujados con D3.js

Tags: jquery, d3.js

Estoy tratando de dibujar un familiograma con d3. Es la primera vez que uso esta biblioteca, pero no puedo arrastrar y soltar los elementos dibujados en el svg, aunque he buscado ejemplos, esta tarea me ha resultado difícil. .

Hasta ahora está dibujando círculos y rectángulos para representar al padre y a la madre, el problema es que no puedo mover los elementos para arreglar la posición de esos elementos y darle la apariencia adecuada ya que de por si son muchas mas convenciones a utilizar.

Gracias de antemano por cualquier ayuda.

Aquí está mi código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>FAM</title>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.14.2/d3.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function () {
                        var svg = d3.select('#svf');//.on("mousedown", mousedown).on("mouseup", mouseup);
                        var container = svg.append("g");
                        var pxy = new Array();
                        svg.on('click', function () {
                            var coords = d3.mouse(this), x = coords[0], y = coords[1];
                            var lnk = $('#dv_conv').find('a[data-pressed="1"]');
                            var conv = lnk.attr('data-conv');

                            if (conv == 1) {
                                pxy = new Array();
                                container.append('circle').attr('cx', x).attr('cy', y).attr('r', 30).attr('stroke-width', 1).attr('stroke', '#000').attr('fill', 'transparent').on("dblclick", clicked);

                            }

                            if (conv == 2) {
                                pxy = new Array();
                                container.append('rect').attr('x', x).attr('y', y).attr('width', 60).attr('height', 60).attr('stroke-width', 1).attr('stroke', '#000').attr('fill', 'transparent').on("dblclick", clicked);
                            }

                            if (conv == 3) {
                                pxy[pxy.length] = x;
                                pxy[pxy.length] = y;

                                pxy[pxy.length] = x;
                                pxy[pxy.length] = y + 30;

                                pxy[pxy.length] = x + 160;
                                pxy[pxy.length] = y + 30;

                                pxy[pxy.length] = x + 160;
                                pxy[pxy.length] = y;

                                container.append('polyline').attr("stroke", '#000').attr('fill', 'none').attr('points', pxy);
                            }
                        });

                        d3.select('body').on('keydown', function () {
                            if (d3.event.keyCode === 27) {
                                $('#lnk_circle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                                $('#lnk_rectangle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                                $('#lnk_line').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                            }
                        });

                        var drag = d3.drag();
                        d3.selectAll("circle").call(d3.drag().on("start", started));

                        function started() {
                            var circle = d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);

                            d3.event.on("drag", dragged).on("end", ended);

                            function dragged(d) {
                                circle.raise().attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
                            }

                            function ended() {
                                circle.classed("dragging", false);
                            }
                        }

                        function clicked(d, i) {
                            //alert('');
                        }
                        /*$('#svg').on('dblclick','circle',function(){
                         alert('');
                         });*/

                        $('#lnk_circle').click(function () {
                            $('#lnk_rectangle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                            $('#lnk_line').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                            $(this).attr('data-pressed', 1);
                            return false;
                        });

                        $('#lnk_rectangle').click(function () {
                            $('#lnk_circle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                            $('#lnk_line').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                            $(this).attr('data-pressed', 1);
                            return false;
                        });

                        $('#lnk_line').click(function () {
                            $('#lnk_circle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                            $('#lnk_rectangle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                            $(this).attr('data-pressed', 1);
                            return false;
                        });
                    });
                </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="dv_conv" style="float: left;width:200px;border:1px solid #000;margin-right: 1px">
                <a href="#" id="lnk_circle" data-pressed="0" data-conv="1">Circle</a><br/>
                <a href="#" id="lnk_rectangle" data-pressed="0" data-conv="2">Rectangle</a><br/>
                <a href="#" id="lnk_line" data-pressed="0" data-conv="3">Line</a><br/>
            </div>

            <div id="dv_familiogram" style="float: left;width:500px;height: 500px;border:1px solid #000;overflow: scroll">

                <svg id="svf"  style="width:500px;height:100%;background-color:#cce7d4"></svg>

            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

```js
$(function () {
                    var svg = d3.select('#svf');//.on("mousedown", mousedown).on("mouseup", mouseup);
                    var container = svg.append("g");
                    var pxy = new Array();
                    svg.on('click', function () {
                        var coords = d3.mouse(this), x = coords[0], y = coords[1];
                        var lnk = $('#dv_conv').find('a[data-pressed="1"]');
                        var conv = lnk.attr('data-conv');

                        if (conv == 1) {
                            pxy = new Array();
                            container.append('circle').attr('cx', x).attr('cy', y).attr('r', 30).attr('stroke-width', 1).attr('stroke', '#000').attr('fill', 'transparent').on("dblclick", clicked);

                        }

                        if (conv == 2) {
                            pxy = new Array();
                            container.append('rect').attr('x', x).attr('y', y).attr('width', 60).attr('height', 60).attr('stroke-width', 1).attr('stroke', '#000').attr('fill', 'transparent').on("dblclick", clicked);
                        }

                        if (conv == 3) {
                            pxy[pxy.length] = x;
                            pxy[pxy.length] = y;

                            pxy[pxy.length] = x;
                            pxy[pxy.length] = y + 30;

                            pxy[pxy.length] = x + 160;
                            pxy[pxy.length] = y + 30;

                            pxy[pxy.length] = x + 160;
                            pxy[pxy.length] = y;

                            container.append('polyline').attr("stroke", '#000').attr('fill', 'none').attr('points', pxy);
                        }
                    });

                    d3.select('body').on('keydown', function () {
                        if (d3.event.keyCode === 27) {
                            $('#lnk_circle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                            $('#lnk_rectangle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                            $('#lnk_line').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                        }
                    });

                    var drag = d3.drag();
                    d3.selectAll("circle").call(d3.drag().on("start", started));

                    function started() {
                        var circle = d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);

                        d3.event.on("drag", dragged).on("end", ended);

                        function dragged(d) {
                            circle.raise().attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
                        }

                        function ended() {
                            circle.classed("dragging", false);
                        }
                    }

                    function clicked(d, i) {
                        //alert('');
                    }
                    /*$('#svg').on('dblclick','circle',function(){
                     alert('');
                     });*/

                    $('#lnk_circle').click(function () {
                        $('#lnk_rectangle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                        $('#lnk_line').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                        $(this).attr('data-pressed', 1);
                        return false;
                    });

                    $('#lnk_rectangle').click(function () {
                        $('#lnk_circle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                        $('#lnk_line').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                        $(this).attr('data-pressed', 1);
                        return false;
                    });

                    $('#lnk_line').click(function () {
                        $('#lnk_circle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                        $('#lnk_rectangle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                        $(this).attr('data-pressed', 1);
                        return false;
                    });
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="dv_conv" style="float: left;width:200px;border:1px solid #000;margin-right: 1px">
            <a href="#" id="lnk_circle" data-pressed="0" data-conv="1">Circle</a><br/>
            <a href="#" id="lnk_rectangle" data-pressed="0" data-conv="2">Rectangle</a><br/>
            <a href="#" id="lnk_line" data-pressed="0" data-conv="3">Line</a><br/>
        </div>

        <div id="dv_familiogram" style="float: left;width:500px;height: 500px;border:1px solid #000;overflow: scroll">

            <svg id="svf"  style="width:500px;height:100%;background-color:#cce7d4"></svg>

        </div>
```